# how to align two input class on the same line?

Tags: php, html

I want to align two input classes next to each other with some space in between them like the following image.
[image]

However, my current output is like this:
[image]

The html code is

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label  for="form-workphoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">input</label>
            <div id="box" class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="workphoneNumber" placeholder="enter">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="add" onclick="add_textbox()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I believe you are using bootstrap. One of the ways: Add  `style="width:40%;float:left;"` to both the input box and button (change the 40% to a value you want, say $60% for input box and 30% for button)

Answer (score 2):

Just add width and margin

```
style="margin-right:5px;width:80%;float:left"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label  for="form-workphoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">input</label>
        <div id="box" class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <input style="margin-right:5px;width:80%;float:left" type="text" class="form-control" name="workphoneNumber" placeholder="enter">
            <input style="width:15%;float:left" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="add" onclick="add_textbox()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label  for="form-workphoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">input</label>
        <div id="box" class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <input style="margin-right:5px;width:80%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top" type="text" class="form-control" name="workphoneNumber" placeholder="enter">
            <input style="width:15%;display:inline-block" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="add" onclick="add_textbox()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label  for="form-workphoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label">input</label>
        <div id="box" class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 d-flex">
            <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" name="workphoneNumber" placeholder="enter">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success m-2" value="add" onclick="add_textbox()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I suggest you to avloid inline styling and use bootstrap classes for good practices**